# Sum across dynamic number of sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a macro that creates a workbook with multiple worksheets named by dates e.g. 12-01-2015, 12-02-2015. Data is entered manually into those worksheets. The last worksheet name is  "TOTAL". Each month the number of worksheets and their names will be different. I am trying to write a piece of code that will sum the data from all sheets into cells located in the worksheet called "Total". My idea was to do it with looping but it does not work despite there are no error messages displayed while macro is running. 
The formula that should be present in "B2" of "Total" worksheet after macro finishes running is not there so my assumption is that summing works only during the time when macro is being executed. I am not sure how to enter "sum" formula into "B2" cell of "Total" worksheet. I would really appreciate any tip that would point me in the right direction. Below there is a piece of code that is not working:

```
Sub Test()

Dim i as Long

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1

             Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("B2").Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(i).Range("B2"))

       Next i

       Worksheets(i).Range("B2").Value = Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("B2").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the formula in the cell or just the total value?

Comment: If you want the total value then change this `Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("B2").Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(i).Range("B2"))` to this: `Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("B2").Value = Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("B2").Value + Worksheets(i).Range("B2").value`

Comment: Formula only, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom User-Defined Function (UDF) that when entered in a cell, sums-up the corresponding cells from all other worksheets within the same  workbook. Let us call it `AutoSum`:

```
Function AutoSum() As Variant
    AutoSum = 0
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Not ws Is Application.ThisCell.Parent Then AutoSum = AutoSum + ws.Range(Application.ThisCell.Address)
    Next
End Function
```

Then you can simply use it in formula in any cell: `=AutoSum()`

Comment: Thank you, A.S.H. I tried to use it but I am doing something wrong. I saved this function in a separate module of the same workbook where I keep my code and then I tried to call it in my procedure by the following line of code:

Comment: Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("B2").Value = AutoSum

Comment: @Trix, No, you simply enter in cell B2 of the worksheet "Totals" the formula `=AutoSum()`. Or from VBA,`Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("B2").Formula = "=AutoSum()"`.

Comment: Are you sure you entered the formula `=AutoSum()`? (dont forget the parenthesis), and that all the involved cells do contain numeric values?? Because ok, if there is a non-numeric string in those cells, you will get `#Value` but that is normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long
Dim t As String


For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
    If i = 1 Then
        t = "=Sum('" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!B2"
    Else
        t = t & ",'" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!B2"
    End If
Next i

Worksheets("TOTAL").Range("B2").Formula = t & ")"

End Sub
```

It builds the formula as it loops then assigns the formula to the cell.

Comment: Thank you, Scott. When I try to run this code I get Run-time error '13'. Do you have an idea where the issue might be?

Comment: @trix use ASH's code just put in the actual cell you want the total in the worksheet total `=autosum` just like any other formula.  If you want to use this what is the value of `t` when it stops?

Comment: @Trix Sorry my bad I had a t where an i should have been.  See edit.

Comment: Thank you for catching that, Scott. I will try in a minute. When I enter ASH's function directly into a cell, I am getting an error: #NAME?

Comment: thank you. Your code seems to be working. The only issue I have with it is when it stops running. I am getting a pop up window very similar to the one when you want to save a new file but it is titled: "Update Values: 2015". When I close it and go to the cell where the formula should be, I can see the formula but also an error " #REF"

Comment: Post the end formula, there is probably a typo.

Comment: I assume you have sheets that have spaces in the name.  I adjusted the code to deal with that.

Comment: @Trix you really should work with ASH to get his to work.  It is cleaner and simpler.

Comment: @Trix you need to mark one as correct, also I was noticing you have other questions that you have not chosen a correct answer.  Hit the green check mark beside the Answer that was the one with which you went.  Otherwise people may stop helping with out the acknowledgment.  Go through your questions and if one was correct please mark it as such.