# Using internal excel sheet name (i.e. sheet1, sheet2, sheet3) to sum a cell across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, sum, cell

I'm trying to sum the same cell across multiple sheets. The number of sheets increases by one each week and will be a new Sheet1. Each sheet will get a date for it's name. The last sheet will have the sum totals. The three sheets prior to that will contain instructions. i.e. 20 sheets, data on sheets 1-16, instructions on sheets 17-19 and totals on sheet 20.

This [Sum across dynamic number of sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343788/sum-across-dynamic-number-of-sheets) question uses a User-defined Function, =autosum, in each cell and could work. I would rather use VBA to create a macro. I know how to get total sheets and sum across all the sheets, where I'm lost is how to sum across (total sheets -4), i.e. sheets 1-16.

code I'm already using is

```
Dim sheets as Integer

sheets = Application.sheets.Count

=SUM('FirstSheet:LastSheet'!D6)
```

How do I get

`=SUM('FirstSheet:(LastSheet-4)'!D6`?

I want to use the internal excel sheet1, sheet2, etc. vs the date name on each sheet, at least for FirstSheet. I can hardcode LastSheet since it won't change.

Comment: What's the exact SUM code you are using now/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use VBA, you can use the default sum formula. I recommend creating two blank sheets (e.g. "Start" and "End"), ensure that "Start" is always before the first sheet you want to some and "End" is always immediately after the last sheet you want to sum. Then, a formula like this would do what you're asking:

```
=SUM(Start:End!A1)
```

Edit: If the name of the first and/or last sheet that should be summed is static, you could avoid using the "start" or "end" placeholders and replace them with the names of the first/last sheets that should be summed.

Comment: That will work.  I can put "Blank" as the first sheet.  I was trying to not confuse the individuals who actually add the new sheets and load the data.  I'll just get with them and make sure they understand to add any new sheets after "Blank".  Thank you.